# How do l link two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

l have a form that is submitting data into a MySQL database and a separate image upload system so l want the images uploaded to be linked to that particular information  when they are  in my database how do l do this....because l want to retrieve them both and output to users....

```
if (empty($_POST)=== false && empty($errors)=== true){

$post_data = array(
   'sold_by'       => $_POST['sold_by'],
   'username'      => $_POST['username'],
   'email'         => $_POST['email'],
   'phone'         => $_POST['phone'],
   'address'       => $_POST['address'],
   'category'      => $_POST['category'],
   'price'         => $_POST['price'],
   'price_title'   => $_POST['price_title'],
   'location'      => $_POST['location'],
   'title'         => $_POST['title'],
   'description'   => $_POST['description'],
```

Comment: another table with a foreign key to link both tables

Comment: Oh ok let me try that rawat